# Laravel 5.6 '/' route found but other routes not found AWS EC2

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, routes, ubuntu-16.04

I am new to laravel and AWS. I am trying to run my application on AWS EC2 apache server. My application is working fine in local system but once I tried to upload code on AWS only index route (i.e '/') is working fine. For other routes, it is giving me **NOT FOUND** error. If I try to run application /index.php/login it is loading a page but js and css are not available.

Code in 000-default.conf file

```
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/public
```

Code in /etc/apache2/apache2.conf file

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

There is no .httacess in root in my application and I restarted apache server after changes. Please guide me what I am missing.

Thank You in advance.

Comment: did you try to change the <directory /var/www to <directory /var/www/public >

Comment: yes in /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf file

Comment: Copy .htaccess from your public folder to root then tell me what happen. It should work

Comment: I don't have htaccess in public folder.In my aws server  below htaccess is present /home/ubuntu/.composer/.htaccess
/home/ubuntu/.composer/cache/.htaccess
/var/www/html/vendor/phenx/php-font-lib/.htaccess

Comment: Did you tried `sudo a2enmod rewrite` and restart apache?

Comment: @carlos yes and I restart apache after each change

Answer (score 1):

I've same issue with *httpd* but I resolve it by adding following with `.htaccess`.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Note that to add `.htaccess` in the public/ directory.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need to setup your virtualhost configurations. Open your default configuration file with `sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` command  (or whatever text editor you use) And replace default configurations with belows

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/public

    <Directory "/var/www/html/public">
            Options +FollowSymLinks
            ReWriteEngine On
            Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I copy paste you code in 000-default.conf file and restart apache but still not working

Comment: @urvisha can you check that your apache log if is there any helpful explanation (`/var/log/apache2/error.log`)

Comment: Tingir Sorry for the delay. Below errors are in apache error log [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 16031] AH00163: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations [core:notice] [pid 16031] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2' [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 16031] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down